# SparkSQL: task taking hours for small input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently facing a strange issue with apache spark 2.1 (scala).
I am running sparkSQL job, which hangs for more than 2 hours on a task:

[image]

The first two tasks take more than 2 hours to complete for 751 input records, which does not make any sense to me.

Moreover, in the logs I can see:

```
18/07/16 14:34:43 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 3974)
18/07/16 14:34:43 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 3974). 16874 bytes result sent to driver
18/07/16 14:34:43 INFO Executor: Finished task 136.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 3873). 18268 bytes result sent to driver
18/07/16 16:44:42 INFO Executor: Finished task 196.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 3921). 17190 bytes result sent to driver
18/07/16 16:44:43 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 7
18/07/16 16:44:43 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 59
```

So it really seems like the executor is not doing anything.

Did anyone face such an issue before or would someone have some insights on this?

Comment: Did you check that there are enough resources?  Can you confirm that there is enough disk space on every node (driver/executors)? Can you confirm that no other spark job is running on the same nodes?

Comment: For resources and disk space, I am pretty sure it is OK. This job is running on a cluster with other spark jobs, however this job hangs at every run on the same tasks, so I don't think that is it due to other spark jobs since it would probably randomly hangs.

Comment: Can you share more details: 1. What is the size of the input data? In which format is it saved? Can you share a simple code which can reproduce the problem (at least at your side)?

Comment: @nsanglar also please provide physical plan of computation, it will help alot